# What is the opposite of a catastrophe?

Tags: single-word-requests

Bad: "It was a catastrophe."

Good: "It was a "??????????."

I think "miracle" almost works, but has connotations I don't intend. What's a word for something that was an incredible success beyond expectation?

Comment: Etymologically, it would be an ***anastrophe***. That doesn’t really work in any situation I can think of, though.

Answer (score 2):

Good: It  was a ***[marvel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/marvel)***!!! (Also a wonder)

> a thing or person that is very surprising or causes a lot of admiration.

(Collins)

Answer (score 1):

**A blessing.**

A beneficial thing that occurs that engenders a feeling of being a gift, something to be grateful for.

Lit. ‘a gift from God’.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/blessing

Answer (score 1):

**[bonanza](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bonanza)**

> A situation which creates a sudden increase in wealth, good fortune, or profits.  *‘As one would expect, most state and local governments responded to this apparent bonanza by increasing spending.’* (Oxford's Lexico)